# MySQL query consolidated report

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

customers

```
id    name
1    customer 1
```

stores

```
id    name   customer_id
1    store 1    1
2    store 2    1
3    store 3    1
```

items

```
id    name   store_id    customer_id    inventory
1    item 1    1            1               10
2    item 2    2            1               12
3    item 3    2            1               18
```

item_attributes

```
id    item_id   store_id    customer_id    inventory
1      1          2            1              4
2      1          3            1              3
3      2          1            1              7
4      2          3            1              0
5      3          1            1              9
```

**What I want is this:**

```
item ID    Item Name    store 1    Store 2    Store 3
1            Item 1       10          4          3
2            Item 2       7          12          0
3            Item 3       9          18          0
```

A customer can have many stores.

Each store can have many items.

Other stores may or may not have the entry in the item_attributes table.

I want to get an consolidated report on item inventory.

My approach is:

Get all the items for the customer 1.

Get all the stores for the customer 1.

Get all records from the item_attributes.

```
foreach($i=0; $i<count($items); $i++){
    foreach($j=0; $j<count($stores); $j++){
        // now I get the item_id and store_id.
        // check if exists in the $item_attr array with this combination.
        // return the inventory if yes, 0 otherwise.
    }
}
```

Is there any easier approach than the one I mentioned above? Any thoughts would appreciated.

Comment: Research pivot table/query. Ot you could use a single query to join the tables, then do the pivot in PHP (or whatever language you are calling SQL from)

Comment: Show the query you are using now.

Comment: It's basically 3 simple selects on the 3 tables and use PHP to do the rest.